# Add a file upload button to chat screen

Tags: react-native-gifted-chat

My RN 0.61.5 app is running the `react-native-gifted-chat 0.13.0`. Here is the render which is pretty plain:

```
render() {
      console.log("In GiftedChat render : ");
      return ( 
          <GiftedChat 
            messages={this.state.messages}
            onSend={messages => this._onSend(messages)}
            user={{_id: this.state.myself.id,
                   name: this.state.myself.name,
                   avatar: this.state.myself.user_data.avatar}}
          />         
      );
    }
```

I would like to add a file upload button (which can open gallery or file manager) by the typing text box allowing user to upload an image or video file. How can I do that? I have searched online and gone over the doc but did not find a way/hook to add a button to the chat screen.

Answer (score 1):

There is a prop called renderActions() in gifted chat docs. It adds a custom action button on the left of the message composer. I have implemented image uploading button by using this.

```js
<GiftedChat
    messages={this.state.messages}
    onSend={this.send}
    ...
    renderActions={() => (
      <React.Fragment>
        <ImgPicker setmsgImgUrl={this.setmsgImgUrl} />
      </React.Fragment>
    )}
/>
```

I have created the ImgPicker component by using codes in the expo docs image picker.
If you want to see the ImgPicker component code, here is the link.

[Github link for the ImgPicker Component Code](https://github.com/shnrndk/office_messenger/blob/master/Components/ImagePicker/ImgPicker.js)